# XMLHttpRequest throws error responseXML = null, but content appears anyway

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

This is my first XMLHttpRequest attempt, and while it works (the content is loaded from the xml file, and displays correctly in the browser), Mozilla Console shows the error:

```
[15:05:54.147] TypeError: xmlTree is null @ http://127.0.0.1/scripts/firstExternal.js:37
```

I don't know how it can be null, if the content loads?

Here is the function, called from the window.onload event:

```
function getXML() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = (function () {
            if (xhr.readyState = 4) {
                if (xhr.status = 200) {
                    var xmlTree = xhr.responseXML;
                    var container = document.getElementById("container");
error here:         var textList = xmlTree.getElementsByTagName("text");
                    for (var i = 0; i<textList.length; i++) {
                        var tempText = document.createTextNode(textList[i].textContent);
                        var tempElem = document.createElement("P");
                        tempElem.appendChild(tempText);
                        container.appendChild(tempElem);
                    }
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText;
                }
            }
        });
        xhr.open("GET","/res/sample.xml",true);
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <text>This is a sentence.</text>
    <text>This is the second sentence.</text>
    <text>ain't one.</text>
    <text>More bric a brac</text>
    <text>Foo, bar, baz.  Fizzbuzz forever.</text>
</xml>
```

EDIT:
The response header:

```
Date: Sat, 01 Feb 2014 23:31:03 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Last-Modified: Sat, 01 Feb 2014 23:28:47 GMT Etag: "21d16-ed-4f160a6f67bb5" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 237 Content-Type: application/xml
```

Comment: i guess that you can't use <xml> try an other one

Comment: @MidoDev - I tried some other names for the root tag like `<note>`, etc.  Didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests to see if the readyState and status are OK are using **assignments** (`=`) instead of **equality** tests (`===`).

Consequently, they are always `true`, so the contents of the `if` are run every time the `readyState` changes.

The last time they run, they are `4` and `200`, so the right data appears.

Every previous time, you'll get an error.

Comment: Haha, of course.  Such a simple oversight, though, shouldn't the answer be `==`, not `===`?

Comment: There are merits to both the equals operator and the strict equals operator. I prefer to default to the strict equals operator since the rules for type conversion on the equals operator are a bit unintuitive so I only use them when I know I need them.

Comment: OK, actually I didn't even know that was a valid comparison, I thought it was a typo.  Thanks for pointing that out, I'll read about the difference.